# Is it possible to render ember elements directly under body tag while staying in the context of the application?

Tags: ember.js

I'm trying to render a header element directly under the `<body>` tag through Ember and am having a hard time pulling it off b/c Ember wraps everything inside the main application `<div>` tag. So, what I'd like to have is a document structure roughly like this:

```
<html>
  <head>
    ...
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
      ... content inside here is controlled by ember application ...
    </header>
    <div class='container'>
      ... main content of the application ...
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

The problem is that if I try to include the `header` tag in the main application template, it gets wrapped inside the application `div`. Anyone know how to pull it off?

Answer (score 1):

How about using named outlets? Your application template would look like:

```
<header>
  {{outlet header}}
</header>

<div class='container'>
  {{outlet main}}
</div>
```

and in your route:

```
App.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  renderTemplate: function() {
    this.render({ outlet: 'header' });
    this.render({ outlet: 'main' });
  }
});
```